# LCD outputs JAPANESE Katakana characters instead of alphanumeric?

Tags: arduino, lcd, arduino-uno

Trying to output a simple string of data "ABCD" using my arduino uno and a LCD you can view in the datasheet link below. My LCD is outputting Japanese characters instead of the string I specify. I've tried several ways in troubleshooting this but haven't yet found a fix. It's clear when you look at the character chart in the datasheet that it's getting the upper bit wrong. Any ideas on what I can try doing.

[Here](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-0420E2Z-NSW-BBW.pdf) is the link to the data sheet for my LCD.

Here is the code:

```
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,5,4,3,2);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(20, 4);
}

void loop() {
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // print the number of seconds since reset:
  lcd.print("ABCD");
}
```

Below is a picture of what it is displaying. Again, it should be printing out ABCD.

[image]

Comment: The character numbers are 193, 194, 195, 204.  Not sure about the 204 - should have been 196 ('D' + 128)

Comment: i've typed in lcd.print((char)193) and it prints out that related character. How do I troubleshoot from here?

Comment: i've typed in lcd.print((char)300) and it displays a comma. On the ASCII chart a comma is decimal 44. I guess i'm still not understanding how I need to fix this.

Comment: Decimal 300 is nine bits. When that (ignored) top bit is chopped off, you're left with decimal 44.

Comment: Do you want to print the number 300 or the character A.  For A use lcd.print((char) 0x41)

Comment: @cup did that and it still displayed the Japanese character. I double checked my circuit and bit D7 is pulled low. Can't pull it high cause the LCD turns off. I want to know how i can print out alphanumeric characters like "ABCD" or "1234" instead of seeing these Japanese characters. It seems like no matter what I put in my function lcd.print() it still prints out these Japanese characters.

Comment: According to your initialization of LiquidCrystal, D7 is on pin 2 - Is that correct?

Comment: Looks more like Japanese than Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

According to the datasheets and your description of the problem, the left-most bit of the "Upper 4 bits" is always set to one. Thus you should check the wirings (I'm not sure which pin but I would check for instance that DB0 is not always stuck to Vdd)

Comment: i've pulled Vdd high. i've tried using the Serial.print(65, BYTE) to see if anything changes and my Arduino tells me that BYTE is not supported anymore.

Comment: Bit D7 is pulled low. When I pull it high the LED turns off.

Comment: I meant that one of the lines is abnormally pulled high because according to the table page 7 of the datasheet, ABCD occurs when the upper 4 bits are (0100) and what you get is what should happen with these upper 4 bits equal to 1100. The leftmost bit is abnormally pulled high.